# Simulation in Excel using probability

Tags: excel, algorithm, simulation

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that can find the most likely probability that a student scored a specific grade on a test.

Only one student can score a grade and only one grade can have a student.

I have limited information about each student.

There are 5 students (1,2,3,4,5)
and the grades possible are only (100,90,80,70,60)

In the spreadsheet a 1 denotes that the student DIDN'T score that grade.

Does anyone know how to make a simulation that I can find the most likely probability of what student scored what grade?

Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a8uUIRzUKsY3DolTM1A0ISqMd-42WCUCiDsxmUT5TKI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: You've given no distributional info. Are we supposed to assume that the assignment of grades is equally likely?  If so, that gives your answer directly with no need for simulation.  If not, you haven't given enough info for anybody to help you.  Regardless of all that, Excel, despite its many other fine uses, is one of the worst software choices you could make for simulation.

Comment: I only have this so far... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a8uUIRzUKsY3DolTM1A0ISqMd-42WCUCiDsxmUT5TKI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @pjs sorry - i'm a student and trying to build a model to do this.  the assignment of grade is equal.

Comment: any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your response in comments, each student has an equal likelihood of getting each grade.  No simulation is necessary.

If you want to simulate it anyway, don't use Excel<sup>*</sup>.  Create a vector of students, and pair it with a shuffled vector of the grades.  Lather, rinse, repeat as many times as you want to see that the student-to-grade matching is uniformly distributed.

---

<sup>*</sup> - To get an idea of how bad Excel can be for random variate generation, enable the Analysis Toolpak, go to "Data -> Data Analysis" on the ribbon, and select "Random Number Generation".  Fill in the tabs that you want 10 variables, number of random numbers 2000, a "Normal" distribution, leave the mean and std dev at 0 and 1, and enter a "Random Seed" value of 123. You will find that the resulting table contains 3 instances of the value "-9.35764". Values that extreme should occur about once per twenty thousand years if you generate a billion a second.  Getting three of them is so extreme that it should happen once per 10<sup>30</sup> times the current estimated age of the universe.  Conclude that a) it's your lucky day, or b) Excel sucks at random numbers, and despite being informed about this as far back as 1998 Microsoft hasn't bothered to fix it.